# Simulate dynamic scoping in Java?

Tags: java, dynamic, simulation, scoping, dynamic-scope

I found this piece of code on dynamic scoping in java. But it confuses me.

[Simulation of dynamic scoping in java](http://www.sploat.com/projects/simulation-of-dynamic-scoping-in-java/)

Could someone please tell me whether is this the way you do dynamic scoping?

```
static void f1() {

        callstack.push(new Hashtable());


        declare("a", new Integer(1));

        System.out.println(getvalue("a"));

        f2();


        System.out.println(getvalue("a"));


        callstack.pop();

    }
```

Comment: Either ... like that or another stack ... or (very easily abused) with [TheadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) variables. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Answer (score 0):

That's crazy talk. Can I suggest you try Perl?

Comment: i want to simulate dynamic scoping, not use a language that has built in support for dynamic scoping.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a strict delineation between what's "static" and what's "dynamic" and does not provide a language construct to blend the two.

If you want a value that's "dynamically scoped", then convert it into an object/method that's evaluated at runtime.

For example, these examples are provided in [Are Java 8 Lambdas Closures?](https://www.bruceeckel.com/2015/10/17/are-java-8-lambdas-closures/) (read for full explanation):

#### Python

```py
# Closures.py

def make_fun():
    # Outside the scope of the returned function:
    n = 0

    def func_to_return(arg):
        nonlocal n
        # Without 'nonlocal' n += arg produces:
        # local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
        print(n, arg, end=": ")
        arg += 1
        n += arg
        return n

    return func_to_return

x = make_fun()
y = make_fun()

for i in range(5):
    print(x(i))

print("=" * 10)

for i in range(10, 15):
    print(y(i))

""" Output:
0 0: 1
1 1: 3
3 2: 6
6 3: 10
10 4: 15
==========
0 10: 11
11 11: 23
23 12: 36
36 13: 50
50 14: 65
"""
```

#### Java ("dynamic scope" disallowed)

```java
// AreLambdasClosures.java
import java.util.function.*;

public class AreLambdasClosures {
    public Function<Integer, Integer> make_fun() {
        // Outside the scope of the returned function:
        int n = 0;
        return arg -> {
            System.out.print(n + " " + arg + ": ");
            arg += 1;
            // n += arg; // Produces error message
            return n + arg;
        };
    }
    public void try_it() {
        Function<Integer, Integer>
            x = make_fun(),
            y = make_fun();
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            System.out.println(x.apply(i));
        for(int i = 10; i < 15; i++)
            System.out.println(y.apply(i));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AreLambdasClosures().try_it();
    }
}
/* Output:
0 0: 1
0 1: 2
0 2: 3
0 3: 4
0 4: 5
0 10: 11
0 11: 12
0 12: 13
0 13: 14
0 14: 15
*/
```

#### Java (convert value into object for runtime evaluation, i.e. "dynamic scope")

```java
// AreLambdasClosures2.java
import java.util.function.*;

class myInt {
    int i = 0;
}

public class AreLambdasClosures2 {
    public Consumer<Integer> make_fun2() {
        myInt n = new myInt();
        return arg -> n.i += arg;
    }
}
```